# Replace <br> in an NSString with a new line

Tags: ios, nsstring, line-breaks

I have an `NSString` like this

`NSString *string = @"textTextTextTextText<br>textTextTextText<br>TextTextText"`

I want to set this `NSString` to be the text of my `UICell` with a new line on each 
 tag found on the string. How could I do that?

I've tried this, without success:

`cell.textLabel.text = [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"<br>"];`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<br>" withString: @"\n"]
```

or, if you're using Swift `Strings`

```
var string = "textTextTextTextText<br>textTextTextText<br>TextTextText"
string = Array(string).reduce("") {$0 + ($1 == "<br>" ? "\n" : $1)}
```

Comment: I don't think that second piece of code could ever work. The `Array(string)` would be an `Array<Element>`, whose elements (single characters) would never compare as equal to  "<br>" (4 characters)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Strange that we read the same answer 8 years after it was given, at quite exactly the same time, and we both think ths doesn't have a chance in hell of ever working.

Comment: @gnasher729 I came from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093986/replace-br-in-an-nsstring-with-a-new-line/12094103?noredirect=1#comment107365197_12094103 , as I suspect you did, too

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString * result =
  [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5:**
If you are using Swift string (you can transform your NSString to String):

```
var string = "line1<br>line2<br>line3"
string = string..replacingOccurrences(of: "<br>", with: "\n"))
```