# Replace <br> with \n in swift

Tags: swift, string

I get a string from server and it contains `<br>` and I want to replace it with `\n`

First I use this method:

```
 let description  = user.description.replacingFirstOccurrence(of: "<br>", with: "\n")
```

But because there is no space before `<br>` this method isn't working
then I use the same method as this link

[Replace <br> in an NSString with a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093986/replace-br-in-an-nsstring-with-a-new-line)

```
 let description = user?.description ?? ""
 let filteredDescription  = Array(description).reduce("") {$0 + ($1 == "<br>" ? "\n" : $1)}
```

But I get this error now:

```
Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(String, @escaping (String, String) -> String)'
```

May I ask anyone to help me?
Thanks

Comment: The "description" method should be used solely for debugging purposes.

Comment: And look for a function with a name "replaceAllOccurences..." or something like that. But it would best to show this all to someone more experienced because I really fear for the worst with your code.

Comment: Read the brand new comments to the answer you are quoting - I'm not the only one who thinks it has no chance of working.

Comment: @gnasher729 Just after posting the code, the page refreshed and I saw your comment. I guess we posted at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using replacingOccurrences instead. Please find the code below

```
let description = "This is a test for testing line break <br> Hope this works as expected."
let filteredDescription  = description.replacingOccurrences(of: "<br>", with: "\n")
```